# elevate terminal to a javascript debug terminal?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am running my app in vs code terminal. There are two instances, therefore two terminals. Each instance has the same set of environment variables with different values. They are managed together via forever.

Is there someway to elevate or promote those two terminals (with the respective environment settings) to a javascript debug terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by "debug terminal"? The [debug console](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-console-repl) is not a terminal

Comment: There is a JavaScript Debug Terminal. Its a special terminal where nodejs apps are thrown into debugging mode when you run them automatically.

Comment: Oh, that's what the [`console` and `internalConsoleOptions` options in the *launch.json*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes) are about, but I don't know whether/how it's possible to choose an already open terminal. You might want to open a feature request for this